# PHP - Get Average Handling Time (AHT) from mySQLi Database

Tags: mysql, sql, time, average

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766987/mysql-query-to-average-time) to try to get the AHT from my database.

**So, the database structure is:**

```
 _____________________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                                     |
|     ticketid    tecnico_id        time_at      visit_hour_in     visit_hour_out     |
|_____________________________________________________________________________________|
|        1             3             08:15            16:03            17:00          |
|        2             7             10:45            11:03            13:00          |
|        3             9             08:05            12:03            14:00          |
|        4             6             08:43            12:03            13:30          |
|        5            10             13:30            14:03            15:45          |
|_____________________________________________________________________________________|
```

Therefore, I would like to get the average handling time by `tecnico_id`.

**I tried with:**

```
SELECT tecnico_id,
  AVG((time_at) - (visit_hour_in)) AS responseTime,
  AVG((visit_hour_in) - (visit_hour_out)) AS activityTime,
  AVG((time_at) - (visit_hour_out)) AS handlingTime
FROM `ticket` GROUP BY tecnico_id ORDER BY `ticket`.`tecnico_id` ASC
```

**It outputs this:**

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
|                                                                           |
|        tecnico_id     responseTime    activityTime        handlingTime    |
|___________________________________________________________________________|
|        3                    0              0                    0         |
|        5                 13.6              0                  13.6        |
|        6      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        7      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        8      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        9      5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        10     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        11     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        18     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        19     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        20     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        21     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        22     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        23     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|        24     5.791946308724833  -0.37583892617449666   5.416107382550336 |
|___________________________________________________________________________|
```

The `5.791946308724833`, `-0.37583892617449666` and `5.416107382550336` are not repeated, I just didn't wanted to format the table.

To convert it to hours, min and secs I use `gmdate('H:i:s', '5.791946308724833')`, (as an example), however... The results are not accurate as they *should be*. What I *need to do*, is getting the difference between those fields, then getting the average, so I can say, as an example:

> tecnico_id's #3 responseTime is 02 hours and 3 minutes, his activity time is 0 hours and 48 minutes and his AHT per ticket is 3 hours and 0 minutes.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to solve this is actually easy. I used this query to make it work.

```
SELECT tecnico_id, COUNT(tecnico_id) as cantidad_tecnico ,
 SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))) as tiempo, 
 (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))/COUNT(tecnico_id)) as promedio
FROM ticket group by tecnico_id asc
```